# C# using flowlayoutpanel as simulate MDI container

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a new winforms application.

I want to simulate MDI functionality with a flowlayoutpanel that will host "many" panels that will have a form embedded into it.

So the workflow would work like this:

1. User click on navigation menu to open a module (the module is a `winform` that will be embedded into a `panel` and this `panel` will expand to fill its container)
2. The user will se the module filled in order to work but has option to minimize it so he can work on other module.
3. When the user click on the minimize icon "custom icon added to the panel", the `panel` will minimize like a title into the `flowcontainerpanel`.
4. The user then can click on other module or double click the existing current opened modules "tiles" to open it again.

Here are some images so I can explain it better.

[image]

Once the "tile" is double clicked the panel should expand and fill:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: It seems you forgot to ask a question :)

Comment: Is how is the best approach to do it :)